# Android timers leak

Tags: android

In my application I'm trying to have particles emanating from possibly multiple touch locations.

I have a class for storing a point and an associated timer:

```
private static class Touch
{
    public Timer timer = new Timer();
    public vec position = new vec();
}
```

Inside the onTouchEvent, in case of MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN I instance a new Touch:

```
Touch t = new Touch();
t.position = new vec(event.getX(id), event.getY(id));
t.timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeredTouchTask(t.position, id), 0, SHOOTING_INTERVAL);
```

and store it inside a map, using the touch id as key.

If MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP gets fired I remove the touch by calling cancel() on the timer and by removing it from the map.

Finally, if the event is of type MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE I simply iterate all the Touch instances inside the map and update the vector coordinates.

This works but sometimes timers won't get removed correctly, sometimes they are kept alive doing nothing and sometimes they keep on actually shooting particles even if I stopped touching the screen.

How could I make this code more robust so it will always behave correctly?

edit1: the code of ACTION_POINTER_UP

I call this method

```
private void removeTouch(int id)
{
    Touch t = _touch.get(id);

    if(t != null)
    {
        if(t.timer != null)
        {
            t.timer.cancel();
            t.timer = null;
        }

        t = null;
        _touch.remove(id);
    }
}
```

edit2: the full listing [LINK](http://pastebin.com/yjd1WwhH)

By examining some logs I found out that for example:
Touch finger #1
Touch finger #2
Touch finger #3
Release finger #3
Release finger #2
Release finger #1

is ok but doing:

Touch finger #1
Touch finger #2
Touch finger #3
Release finger #1
Release finger #2
Release finger #3

leaks the last timer. I think I'm definitively messing with id's and indexes.

Comment: Can you post the code when you handle the ACTION_POINTER_UP and cancel the timer?

Comment: Updated... probably not very well done.

Comment: That looks all good to me... maybe the best would be for you to add some debug prints (with the id) and maybe you can figure out some pattern of what test fails (the != null), or if the call to cancel happens but it not really effective...

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your use of `getX(id)`, etc, I'm guessing `id` is the pointer *index*, not the pointer *id*. Pointer indexes aren't guaranteed to stay persistent across touch events, so you may not be finding the same timer when you use it for later events.

You should use the pointer id to track which is which. [getPointerId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPointerId%28int%29) will give you that for each index.

If you haven't read it already, I highly recommend reading [Making Sense of Multitouch](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html) on the Android blog.

Comment: I'm using the correct value I think. First I get the index with event.getActionIndex(), then the id variable gets assigned to event.getPointerId(index).

Comment: Are you sure? Because `getX()` takes the pointer index, not id, and you're using `id` there, and using the same `id` in the next line to when constructing your `TimeredTouchTask()`. One or the other doesn't seem right.

Comment: The documentation says index but apparently is referring to the id? About getX >> "Returns the X coordinate of this event for the given pointer index (use getPointerId(int) to find the pointer identifier for this index). Whole numbers are pixels; the value may have a fraction for input devices that are sub-pixel precise." I'm not sure but my coordinates look correct.

Comment: The documentation is correct, it uses the index. I've used it multiple times. You can see for yourself in the sample code at the blog post I linked, also. I can't say why your coordinates seem right, but maybe if you post the code dealing with index/id handling, it would clear things up.

Comment: Ops, you're right! I edited my question with the method code.

Comment: I think I found the problem! Because I was using the id I wrote a check at line 66/67, but it actually removed the reference to a valid timer. Now seems to work.